zalaligne last system not working in Gregorian Chant musixgre library
It is needed to code the "Canticum Zachariae" using Musixtex with musixgre library, but the zalaligne is not working in the last system. The basic code is as follow:
\documentclass[%
border={2pt 7pt 2pt -7pt},% left bottom right top
%border=8pt
varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{scalerel}%Escalar símbolos
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr
\input musixlit
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amssymb}% %$\shortmid$ and $\mid$
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\hsize=\linewidth%
\resetlyrics
\setlyrics{Letras}{Be-ne-{\hspace{1.5cm}-dic-tus Dó-mi-nus} De-us Is-ra-el: {\hspace{4.5cm}quia visitávit, et fecit redemptiónem} ple-bis su-{\ae}: Et er-{{\hspace{2.5cm}-éxit  cornu  sal}}-{\'u}-tis no-bis: {{\hspace{3.5cm}in domo David}} pú-e-ri-sui. Si-cut {{\hspace{3.1cm}locútus est per}} os san-ctó-rum, {{\hspace{4.5cm}qui a s{\ae}culo sunt, prophe}}-t{\'a}-rum ei-us: Sa-l{\'u}-{{\hspace{0.7cm}tem ex inimicis nostris, et de manu ómnium}} qui o-dér-unt nos:}%
\setsongraise{1}{0.15cm}
\font\A=phvb8t at 6pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 13pt% added for letter type.
\instrumentnumber{1}
\nobarnumbers
\setlines14
\setclef1{4000}
\setstaffs11
\setaltoclefsymbol1\gregorianCclef
\newcommand{\ustt}[1]{\raisebox{0.2\Interligne}{\kern-1.4pt \ust {#1}\kern1.4pt}}% normal size \ust centered and put higher for notes on a line
%
\newcommand{\usttt}[1]{\zcharnote {#1}{\A\textbf\medtype \kern0.3pt\raisebox{0.1\Interligne}-\kern0.3pt}}% shorter \ust
%
\newcommand{\btt}[1]{\zcharnote {#1}{\A\textbf{\kern1.16pt \raisebox{-0.9\Interligne}{\lilyGlyph{rests.M1neomensural}}\kern-1.16pt}}}% vertical bar below center of note head (original distance) 
\newcommand{\ptt}[1]{\kern-4pt\pt {#1}\kern4pt}% point closer to note head (original distance is defined for larger \nq)
%
%\newcommand{\caeg}{\zcharnote{5}{\hbsk\begin{tikzpicture}%Barra Vertical
%\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.35,-0.295) -- ++(0,0.15); %
%\end{tikzpicture}}}% works, but quite complicated if there is an existing symbol in amssymb
%
\newcommand{\caeg}{\charnote{b}{\kern-4.1pt$\A\textbf\shortmid$\kern4.1pt}\hbsk}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\dsbr}{\notes\zcharnote M{\kern-1.1pt$\A\textbf\mid\hspace{-0.125cm}\mid$\kern1.1pt}\hbsk\en}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\sbr}{\notes\zcharnote M{\kern-1.1pt$\A\textbf\mid$\kern1.1pt}\hbsk\en}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\sbre}{\zcharnote O{\kern-1.6pt$\A\textbf\mid$}}% see differences in spacing
%
\startpiece%
\A\assignlyrics{1}{Letras}%
\addspace{0.5\afterruleskip}%
\notes\diapunc{M}\isluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tslur0{a}\nolyr\diapunc{a}\lyr\Hpause{a}{2}\sk\sk\sk\diapunc{_b}\diapunc{a}\diapunc{N}\diapunc{a}\diapunc{a}\en%
\zalaligne%
\notes\lyr\Hpause{a}{5}\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\diapunc{N}\diapunc{M}\isluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tslur0{a}\nolyr\diapunc{a}\isluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tslur0{M}\nolyr\diapunc{M}\en%
\zalaligne%
\notes\diapunc{M}\isluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tslur0{a}\nolyr\diapunc{a}\lyr\Hpause{a}{4}\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\diapunc{_b}\diapunc{a}\diapunc{N}\diapunc{a}\en%
\zalaligne%
\notes\lyr\Hpause{a}{5}\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\diapunc{N}\diapunc{M}\isluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tslur0{a}\nolyr\diapunc{a}\isluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tslur0{M}\nolyr\diapunc{M}\en%
\zalaligne%
\notes\diapunc{M}\isluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tslur0{a}\nolyr\diapunc{a}\lyr\Hpause{a}{5}\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\diapunc{_b}\diapunc{a}\diapunc{N}\diapunc{a}\en%
\zalaligne%
\notes\lyr\Hpause{a}{7}\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\diapunc{N}\diapunc{M}\isluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tslur0{a}\nolyr\diapunc{a}\isluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tslur0{M}\nolyr\diapunc{M}\en%
\zstoppiece%
%\nolyr%
%\lyricsoff%
\end{music}
\end{document}

The current output is as follow:


When I compile with LuaLaTeX, musixflx and compile again, I don't see any problem: everything is in line.

Solved (Thanks Peters):
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[%
border={2pt 7pt 2pt -7pt},% left bottom right top
%border=8pt
varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{scalerel}%Escalar símbolos
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr%
\input musixlit%
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input musixps%
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amssymb}% %$\shortmid$ and $\mid$
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\hsize=\linewidth%
\resetlyrics
\setlyrics{Letras}{Be-ne-{\hspace{1.5cm}-dic-tus Dó-mi-nus} De-us Is-ra-el: {\hspace{4.5cm}quia visitávit, et fecit redemptiónem} ple-bis su-{\ae}: Et er-{{\hspace{2.3cm}-éxit  cornu  sal}}-{\'u}-tis no-bis: {{\hspace{4.1cm}in domo David}} pú-e-ri-sui. Si-cut {{\hspace{2.1cm}locútus est per}} os san-ctó-rum, {{\hspace{5.5cm}qui a s{\ae}culo sunt, prophe}}-t{\'a}-rum ei-us: Sa-l{\'u}-{{\hspace{0.7cm}tem ex inimicis nostris, et de manu ómnium}} qui o-dér-unt nos:}%
\setsongraise{1}{0.15cm}
\font\A=phvb8t at 6pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 13pt% added for letter type.
\instrumentnumber{1}
\nobarnumbers
\setlines14
\setclef1{4000}
\setstaffs11
\setaltoclefsymbol1\gregorianCclef
\newcommand{\ustt}[1]{\raisebox{0.2\Interligne}{\kern-1.4pt \ust {#1}\kern1.4pt}}% normal size \ust centered and put higher for notes on a line
%
\newcommand{\usttt}[1]{\zcharnote {#1}{\A\textbf\medtype \kern0.3pt\raisebox{0.1\Interligne}-\kern0.3pt}}% shorter \ust
%
\newcommand{\btt}[1]{\zcharnote {#1}{\A\textbf{\kern1.16pt \raisebox{-0.9\Interligne}{\lilyGlyph{rests.M1neomensural}}\kern-1.16pt}}}% vertical bar below center of note head (original distance) 
\newcommand{\ptt}[1]{\kern-4pt\pt {#1}\kern4pt}% point closer to note head (original distance is defined for larger \nq)
%
%\newcommand{\caeg}{\zcharnote{5}{\hbsk\begin{tikzpicture}%Barra Vertical
%\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.35,-0.295) -- ++(0,0.15); %
%\end{tikzpicture}}}% works, but quite complicated if there is an existing symbol in amssymb
%
\newcommand{\caeg}{\charnote{b}{\kern-4.1pt$\A\textbf\shortmid$\kern4.1pt}\hbsk}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\dsbr}{\notes\zcharnote M{\kern-1.1pt$\A\textbf\mid\hspace{-0.125cm}\mid$\kern1.1pt}\hbsk\en}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\sbr}{\notes\zcharnote M{\kern-1.1pt$\A\textbf\mid$\kern1.1pt}\hbsk\en}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\sbre}{\zcharnote O{\kern-1.6pt$\A\textbf\mid$}}% see differences in spacing
%
\startpiece%
\A\assignlyrics{1}{Letras}%
\addspace{0.5\afterruleskip}%
\notes\diapunc{M}\ilsluru1{N}\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tlslur1{a}\nolyr\diapunc{a}\lyr\Hpause{a}{2}\sk\sk\sk\diapunc{_b}\diapunc{a}\diapunc{N}\diapunc{a}\diapunc{a}\en%
\zalaligne%
\notes\lyr\Hpause{a}{5}\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\diapunc{N}\diapunc{M}\isluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tslur0{a}\nolyr\diapunc{a}\isluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tslur0{M}\nolyr\diapunc{M}\en%
\zalaligne%
\notes\diapunc{M}\isluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tslur0{a}\nolyr\diapunc{a}\lyr\Hpause{a}{4}\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\diapunc{_b}\diapunc{a}\diapunc{N}\diapunc{a}\en%
\zalaligne%
\notes\lyr\Hpause{a}{5}\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\diapunc{N}\diapunc{M}\isluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tslur0{a}\nolyr\diapunc{a}\isluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tslur0{M}\nolyr\diapunc{M}\en%
\zalaligne%
\notes\diapunc{M}\isluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tslur0{a}\nolyr\diapunc{a}\lyr\Hpause{a}{5}\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\diapunc{_b}\diapunc{a}\diapunc{N}\diapunc{a}\en%
\zalaligne%
\notes\lyr\Hpause{a}{7}\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\diapunc{N}\diapunc{M}\isluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tslur0{a}\nolyr\diapunc{a}\isluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tslur0{M}\nolyr\diapunc{M}\en%
\zstoppiece%
%\nolyr%
%\lyricsoff%
\end{music}
\end{document}

I am using TexStudio, so to force use the lualatex we need to include in the first line: % !TeX program = lualatex
The output is as follow:

